# changing database connection for JBatch in Payara Micro

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-processing, payara

I don't know how to indicate to Payara Micro that it should use my database for storing JBatch tables instead of the default H2Pool. (tables like jbatchCHECKPOINTDATA etc.)

Almost impossible to find any documentation on that.